# Run Time Error 3078 when table name is correct

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've checked a few articles related to this with no answer working to solve my own issue.

I'm trying to duplicate all records in `tbl_MBR_MiscSteps` having value:

`CO = Forms!frm_BP10_Tablet_MBR_Process!CO`

And changing it to:

`Forms!frm_BP10_Tablet_ViewMBR!TxtSaveAs`.

I keep getting cannot find `'|1'` field in criteria expression and when I try the immediate window, I get error

> 3078: Input table not found.

I also checked `?currentdb.TableDefs("tbl_MBR_MiscSteps").Name` and got `tbl_MBR_MiscSteps`

Can someone please tell me what my code is missing?

```
Private Sub Command617_Click()
Dim sSQL As String
q2 = Chr$(34) & Chr$(34)
dq = Chr$(34) 'double quotes

sSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_MBR_MiscSteps (CO, Step, Tank, RawMaterial, Weight, 
Amount, QuantityWeighed, QuantityDispensed, ScaleID, StartingAmount, " _
& "StartingAmountxBCoatingSolutionNeeded, ContainerTankID, 
NitrogenIsFlowing, Screen, StartTime, StopTime, CompletedByDate, 
CheckedByDate, CommentsBy) SELECT " _
& dq & Replace(Nz([TxtSaveAs]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([Step]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([Tank]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([RawMaterial]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([Weight]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([Amount]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([QuantityWeighed]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([QuantityDispensed]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([ScaleID]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([StartingAmount]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([StartingAmountxBCoatingSolutionNeeded]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([ContainerTankID]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([NitrogenIsFlowing]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([Screen]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([StartTime]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([StopTime]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([CompletedByDate]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([CheckedByDate]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& dq & Replace(Nz([CommentsBy]), dq, q2) & dq & "," _
& "FROM tbl_MBR_MiscSteps " _
& "WHERE CO = Forms!frm_BP10_Tablet_MBR_Process!CO"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a highly unusual SQL clause. You're inserting values from a certain table into itself, but from variable field names into constant field names? In a reasonable database setup, I can't imagine a valid use case for such a query.

Comment: Anyway, there's an obvious error: you've got a `,` before your `FROM`, and you're missing a space there as well. It's probably not the only error, though.

Comment: The reason for the unusual clauses is because the data is stored with html tags. This clause strips them of it... I tried your suggestion to no avail. I still get error 3078. I am indeed trying to insert into a tbl from itself. Is there a better SQL for this? Thanks tho!

Comment: Sounds like an UPDATE query would be more suitable?

Comment: Not really. I work for a vitamin company and these records belong to recipes, Sometimes there is a small change in the recipe which causes a change in [CO]. All records are tied together using [CO] so they need to be duplicated, changing the value of [CO] to the match new recipe. That way all untouched records are still presented when the new [CO] is entered. The old recipe may be called up at a later date.

Comment: Why are the records stored as HTML though? That's definitely causing you major pain here. This would be much more simple if the data was stored in valid SQL format and the front end handled the HTML.

Comment: I fixed it. Adding the table name to all SELECT fields (i.e. tbl1.Field1) did the trick. It's now duplicating perfectly, changing the [CO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (completed untested):

```
Private Sub Command617_Click()
    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = sSQL & "INSERT INTO "
    sSQL = sSQL & "    tbl_MBR_MiscSteps "
    sSQL = sSQL & "    ("
    sSQL = sSQL & "        CO, Step, Tank, RawMaterial, Weight, Amount , QuantityWeighed, QuantityDispensed, "
    sSQL = sSQL & "        ScaleID, StartingAmount, StartingAmountxBCoatingSolutionNeeded, ContainerTankID, "
    sSQL = sSQL & "        NitrogenIsFlowing, Screen, StartTime, StopTime, CompletedByDate, CheckedByDate, CommentsBy"
    sSQL = sSQL & "    ) "
    sSQL = sSQL & "SELECT"
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([TxtSaveAs]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([Step]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([Tank]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([RawMaterial]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([Weight]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([Amount]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([QuantityWeighed]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([QuantityDispensed]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([ScaleID]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([StartingAmount]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([StartingAmountxBCoatingSolutionNeeded]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([ContainerTankID]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([NitrogenIsFlowing]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([Screen]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([StartTime]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([StopTime]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([CompletedByDate]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([CheckedByDate]), "", """") & "","
    sSQL = sSQL & "    "" & Replace(Nz([CommentsBy]), "", """") & "" "
    sSQL = sSQL & "FROM"
    sSQL = sSQL & "    tbl_MBR_MiscSteps "
    sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE"
    sSQL = sSQL & "    CO = Forms!frm_BP10_Tablet_MBR_Process!CO"
    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Comment: I already fixed this issue by adding the table name to all my SELECT fields. However, this option worked too, so I'm marking it as the answer. Thanks again!